# How to change Cryptography's Method at TLS protocol on Localhost(XAMPP)?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, localhost, twofish

Hi =) I Want to ask a question about Cryptography..

---

How to change Cryptography's Method at TLS protocol on Localhost(XAMPP) ?
I want to use Twofish as Simmetric Cryptography, and RSA for PKC....

Thank You =)

Answer (score 3):

This does not work like this. SSL has a set a cipher suites, which consist of a combination of symmetric cipher (e.g. AES, RC4..), key exchange (RSA, DH, ECDH..) and authorization (RSA, DSS...). Twofish is not part of the TLS cipher lists, see `openssl ciphers -V` for the cipherlists supported of your installation.